# Check a condition in list except for last entry using linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list contains

```
List<decimal> number= new List<decimal>();
        number.Add(1);
        number.Add(0);
        number.Add(1);
```

Need to check if number list contains any values greater than 0 except for the last entry/list node using LINQ

test case
1
1
0  => false

0
0
1 =>true

I had tried something like this

```
number.Where(s => s > 0).Skip(number.Count).Any()
```

which will returns a boolean value. But this line of code  always returns false .

Comment: I don't think I understand, so perhaps others feel the same. To clarify:
Do you want to check whether it's a list of numbers where only the last entry is greater than zero? What would 0 0 0 yield for example?

Comment: `number.Take(number.Count - 1).Where(s => s > 0).Any()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing value from the original list, you can skip last value by considering only (number.Count-1) values for processing. For eg.

```
List<decimal> number= new List<decimal>();
    number.Add(1);
    number.Add(0);
    number.Add(1);    
var exists = number.Take(number.Count-1).Any(x => x > 0);
```

Comment: OP expects _test case 1 1 0 => false_, but this solution returns true

Comment: This method returns the exact opposite of what the test cases presented. It was a tricky question then. Should be `number.Take(number.Count - 1).All(n => n == 0);`

Answer (score 1):

If you NuGet Microsoft's Interactive Extensions with the ID "System.Interactive" - then you can do this:

```
var result = number.SkipLast(1).Where(x => x > 0).Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand from "to check if number list contains any values greater than 0 except for the last entry/list node using LINQ" you don't want to check last value, so just remove it from list and check other items:

```
List<decimal> number= new List<decimal>();
    number.Add(1);
    number.Add(0);
    number.Add(1);

    number.RemoveAt(number.Count - 1);
    var exists = number.Any(x => x > 0);
```

Or if you want to check only last element:

```
    number.Take(number.Count-1).Any(x => x > 0).Dump();
```

Comment: OP expects _test case 1 1 0 => false_, but this solution returns true

Comment: What I'm understand from "to check if number list contains any values greater than 0 except for the last entry/list node using LINQ" and given example is not matches.

Answer (score 0):

Skip will skip the number of objects in the sequence and not the object at the specified index.
Here you are skipping all the objects in the sequence and asking if there are any. So it returns false always(Assuming variable defaultdata in your example is typo for variable number).

Try this.

```
var res = number.Where((num, index) => index != number.Count - 1 && num > 0).Any();
```

Note: I do not have enough reputation points to comment as I'm new to StackOverFlow. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: OP expects _test case 1 1 0 => false_, but this solution returns true